# Limiting referrers to debug/localhost (google dev console)

Tags: java, android

H guys, I just need someone to point me to the limiting referrers button in regards to debuging using a google api. I've been getting the following error in a JSON response, "There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed."

Of course I did research and found out theres a whitelist somewhere but since google's api console keeps changing all the previous posts and advice is obsolete.

Notification endpoint seem like a way to do it but unfortunately when i try to submit anything it says "you do not have permission" 
Note that I am using the old console... If you know where it is on new console please let me know.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For youtube API in particular you should create a browser key!